# MySQL DATA Truncation Error occuring from Java application but not directly on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using the JDBC driver to connect to a mysql database and using the "LOAD DATA INFILE" command in my java application to load(insert) a text file into the database. I am getting the following error:  **Data truncation: Data too long for column *xxx* at row 1**.

However if I load the same text file manually by logging into the database and entering the SQL manually, the data loads fine.

Can someone pelase tell me what the error might be?

I am running this on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 and the jdk version is 1.5.0_16 if that helps

This is the function used to load the data

```
    public static void loaddata(Connection conn, String filename, String tablename)
{
    try{
    Statement stmt = null;
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    File file = new File(filename);
    file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "\\\\");
    String cmd = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"
            + file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "\\\\")
            + "' INTO TABLE " + tablename + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'^\'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(cmd);
    System.out.println("cmd     :" + cmd);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the function to create the JDBC connection:

```
    public static Connection createConnection()
{
    Connection conn=null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }       
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String url = ""; //URL mentioned in the actual code
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (SQLException sqe1) {
        sqe1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: @AbstractChaos I have added the functions I am using to load.

Comment: @user1004985 does the output of the `System.out.println("cmd     :" + cmd);` match exactly to your manual sql? and is your file like 'data^data^data^data'?

Comment: @AbstractChaos sry for the late reply..... yes the cmd variable matches my manual command and the data is the way you described, in the file.

Comment: Try changing `\'^\'` to `'^'`... just a hunch :)

Comment: @AbstractChaos it was initially '^' itself but the mysql was throwing a syntax error. Hence I changed it

Comment: If you saw the output of `System.out.println("cmd :" + cmd);` then the statement has been executed with no exception so I cant see what is wrong unless mysql is ignoring the data

Comment: Try it with a shortest possible data file, like `a^b`. What happens?

Comment: @jarekczek I tried that....with only the first record of the data file. I am getting the same error. However if I give some test data, or other valid record for that matter, it is working fine.

Comment: I guess we can't help you, but you can do it yourself. Find the minimal offending sample. If you're still stuck, you may publish this example together with the table structure. If possible, the table structure could also be simiplified.